Validate underline appears while hovering on tab options
I am trying to validate below use case through test automation in Java and Selenium but unable to get an idea about how to proceed.
Use Case- In expedia.com, home page displays 6 tabs on top of the page as Stays, Flights, Cars etc.. When I hover on these tabs a black underline appears at the bottom of these tabs. I want to validate with test automation that this black underline is displayed when I am hovering on the tab options. Providing a screenshot here as reference. Thank you in advance for any help you can offer.

I have tried for solutions in google and youtube.
